# Resizing a screen image, from range of cells, on your clipboard before pasting into new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a situation where I am copying a range of cells, selecting and copying them as a screen image, and pasting them into a new sheet and location.

```
Worksheets("LMC_Model").Range("G1:X34").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
Worksheets("PDF Page").Paste _
    Destination:=Worksheets("PDF Page").Range("a26")
```

This works well, but the screen image is too large and needs to be resized before pasting in the final location.  What are ways to resize the image before pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to paste the picture and then resize it. Since it will already be selected after pasting, you can use this afterwards:

```
Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
Selection.ShapeRange.Width = DesiredPixelWidth
Selection.ShapeRange.Height = DesiredPixelHeight
```